# migrate from renderer to renderer2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, angular-renderer2

I migrated an project from Angular 7 to 8 and I had to change the Renderer class to Renderer2 and I am facing the following error:

```js
ERROR Error: Template error: Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
    at createUnknownPropertyError (vendor.js:83083)
    at validateAgainstUnknownProperties (core.js:12699)
    at elementPropertyInternal (core.js:12604)
    ...
```

How was the class with the Renderer:

```js
import { OnInit, Directive, Input, Renderer, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Loader } from './loader';

@Directive({
    selector: '[asCardLoader]'
})

export class CardDirective implements OnInit {

    private nativeElement: Node;
    private loaderElement: Node;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private element: ElementRef) {
        this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.loader) {
            this.initLoader();
        }

    showLoading() {
        const divElement = this.renderer.createElement(this.nativeElement, 'div');
        this.renderer.setElementClass(divElement, 'card-loading', true);
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(divElement, 'display', 'block');
        this.loaderElement = divElement;
        const nextElem = this.element.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
        const parent = this.element.nativeElement.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(divElement, nextElem);

// other methods
```

What I've tried with renderer2

```js
import { OnInit, Directive, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Loader } from './loader';

@Directive({
    selector: '[asCardLoader]'
})
export class CardLoaderDirective implements OnInit {

    private nativeElement: Node;
    private loaderElement: Node;

    @Input()
    private loader: Loader;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) {
        this.nativeElement = element.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.loader) {
            this.initLoader();
        }
    }

    showLoading() {
        const divElement = this.renderer.createElement('div');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.nativeElement, divElement);
        this.renderer.addClass(divElement, 'card-loading');
        this.renderer.setStyle(divElement, 'display', 'block');
        this.loaderElement = divElement;
        const nextElem = this.element.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
        const parent = this.element.nativeElement.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(divElement, nextElem);
    }
```

With renderer2, the creatElement method, despite having the same name, does not work the same way anymore and I didn’t understand very well from the documentation the correct way that this transition should be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeElement (div) I assume it has disabled property, because I don't see any where in your examples disabled property,

The  element doesn't have a disabled property.
you can use the example down if you need to add disabled without error

`<div [attr.disabled]="condition  ? true : null">`